# How can i add a class to the body depending on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a tag to the existing id , the current HTML is

```
<div id="home" class="pagebody"></div>
```

and i need to add an additional class to the pagebody ONLY if the url has "MODULE=" in it.

So when the url contains "MODULE=" , the appended html will look like this

```
<div id="home" class="pagebody hpmessage"></div>
```

I don't have access to the HTML to manually change this , so i have to use JavaScript / jquery to add the additional class and it must only be added to those urls containing "MODULE=" , any ideas ?

examples of some of the vast URLs are:

```
http://mysite/2014/home/20832
http://mysite/2014/home/20832/standings
http://mysite/2014/home/20832?MODULE=MESSAGE
http://mysite/2014/home/20832?MODULE=MESSAGE1
http://mysite/2014/home/20832?MODULE=MESSAGE2
```

Comment: where is the url MODULE ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( window.location.href.indexOf('MODULE=') != -1) {
    $('#home').addClass('hpmessage')
}
```

Get the current location, check if it contains `MODULE-`, and if so add a class ?

Comment: ty adeneo works perfectly ;) will tag this as answered when clock expires

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS version:

```
if ( window.location.search.indexOf( 'MODULE=' ) > -1 )
    document.body.classList.add( 'hpmessage' );
```